# How to update listView after item has been deleted from database?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

when user long click on one of listViews elements, new dialog appears asking if he want to remove that item from database. If so, then in that dialogs fragment onCreateDialog method, I remove item from database. Here is the issue: how to refresh listView which is in main fragment?

Here is my mainFragment function to handle ListView:

public void handleNotes(final ListView notesListView) {

```
if (database.getNoteCount() != 0) {
    notesListView.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(getActivity(), database.getAllNotes()));

    notesListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView textViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textViewId.getText().toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            DeleteNoteFragment newFragment = new DeleteNoteFragment(database, that, notesListView, Integer.parseInt(textViewId.getText().toString()));
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "deleteConfirmation");

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

And here is the onCreateDialog:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete_note)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_delete_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    database.removeNote(i);
                    mainFragment.handleNotes(notesListView);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_delete_denny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the item from your `ListAdapter` as well, by using the following code.

```
adapter.remove(item);
```

Then use the following code to refresh your adapter alongwith your `ListView`

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Should I pass adapter to Dialog fragments constructor and handle it in onCreateDialog method? In that case, adapter is going to become final, won't it stop adapter from refreshing?

Comment: The adapter can be refreshed using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` even if you declare it as final since by doing so you aren't assigning any new values to it, you're simply refreshing it's contents using a built-in method.